# Exposing or listening to a http port on google cloud instance

Tags: ubuntu, google-compute-engine, node.js

I have a google cloud instance (Ubuntu 20.04) where I tried to run a nodejs app and expose it to port 80.

Here my server.js code:

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  http = require('http'),
  httpServer = http.Server(app);
var basicAuth = require("express-basic-auth");
app.use(basicAuth({
    users: { 'admin': 'admin' },
    challenge: true
}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.listen(80);
```

Locally it runs perfectly (e.g. localhost:80 in my local machine browser) but in the google cloud instance it produces an error message:

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1263:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1328:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1415:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/user/development/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/development/server.js:14:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1307:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Then I tried to create a firewall rule so that I can expose a different port from this instance. So I created a firewall rule to allow connections from any ip (0.0.0.0/0) to hit tcp:8000 and added this tagged rule to the instance and restarted it.

Now I changed the server accordingly to expose port 8000:

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  http = require('http'),
  httpServer = http.Server(app);
var basicAuth = require("express-basic-auth");
app.use(basicAuth({
    users: { 'admin': 'admin' },
    challenge: true
}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.listen(8000);
```

This time the server ran without any error message in the google cloud instance but when I hit the public_ip:8000 in my browser the request gets timed out.

Can someone help me configuring the google cloud instance so that it can be run either in port 80 or port 8000?

Doing `curl INTERNAL_IP` results in

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.142.0.5 port 80: Connection refused
```

Doing `curl -p admin:admin localhost:8000` and `curl -p admin:admin INTERNAL_IP:8000` returns with printing the index.html file in the terminal.

Comment: You asked if you were missing something. You did not check the firewall.

Comment: My bad, I rephrased my question. I think I do not have the knowledge to configure the server to open up those ports. Could you help with some elaborate steps?

Comment: **1.** Please check your app from your VM instance with command `curl INTERNAL_IP` and update your question with result. **2.** Do you use same [network tag](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) on your VM and in your firewall rule? **3.** Have you checked with `PUBLIC_IP:8000` or `http://PUBLIC_IP:8000`? **4.** Please try to set INTERNAL_IP instead of 0.0.0.0 in your application and than check again `http://PUBLIC_IP:8000`.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza 
1. Doing `curl INTERNAL_IP` results in "Port 80: Connection Refused", I think it is because the server never ran in Port 80 because of nodejs`Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80`
2. I double checked the tag.
3. I just checked `http://PUBLIC_IP:8000`, now it is working!! My guess is before I was hitting `https://PUBLIC_IP:8000`, that is why it wasn't working.

Comment: Now that I can open port 8000, is it not possible to open port 80 instead, in the same fashion?

Comment: Great, so `http://PUBLIC_IP:8000` is working. The reason for it could be redirect to HTTPS it's default behavior in modern browsers, i.e. `PUBLIC_IP:8000` will try to open `https://PUBLIC_IP:8000` instead of `http://PUBLIC_IP:8000`.

Comment: You can open port 80 in the same way, just check with `http://PUBLIC_IP` instead of `PUBLIC_IP`.

Comment: But when I try to run the app in port 80, it doesn't even run because of the nodejs error: `Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80`. When I search for the solution it is said in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068712/error-listen-eacces-0-0-0-080-osx-node-js  that I need to use something like Nginx. But my question is if I can expose port 8000 without any proxy than can I not expose port 80 in similar fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [article](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html):

> The TCP/IP port numbers below 1024 are special in that normal users
> are not allowed to run servers on them. This is a security feature, in
> that if you connect to a service on one of these ports you can be
> fairly sure that you have the real thing, and not a fake which some
> hacker has put up for you.

**To run Node.js application on port** **`80`** without [NGINX reverse proxy](https://medium.com/@vishnuit18/setting-up-reverse-proxy-for-nodejs-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04-server-1c629b81dae9) you should at first [configure GCP Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) in the same way as for port `8000` and after that you should choose from the possible solutions below:

1. Use [authbind](https://medium.com/@steve.mu.dev/setup-authbind-on-mac-os-6aee72cb828):

```
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install -y authbind
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chown %user% /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chmod 755 /etc/authbind/byport/80
authbind node server.js
```

replace `%user%` with your username.

2. Use [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) and [authbind](https://medium.com/@steve.mu.dev/setup-authbind-on-mac-os-6aee72cb828):

```
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install -y authbind
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chown %user% /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chmod 755 /etc/authbind/byport/80
```

replace `%user%` with the user that will be running `pm2` and add an alias to the user that runs pm2 profile, e.g. `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` (*note* you will need to run `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc` immediately after):

```
+alias pm2='authbind --deep pm2'
```

then, run:

```
pm2 update
```

and try your app with pm2:

```
pm2 start app.js
```

3. Use [iptables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) to simply redirect traffic:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000
```

4. Use [`libcap`](https://gist.github.com/firstdoit/6389682) to *enable all node programs to bind on any port* lower than 1024:

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' $(which node)
```

**Do not run your app with root permissions**:

```
$ sudo node app.js
```

or

```
$ sudo su -
# node app.js
```

It's better to use full address path `http://PUBLIC_IP:PORT` instead of just `PUBLIC_IP:PORT` in case of any issues.

Comment: I liked the solution number 3 better as it gives me a flexibility of running multiple nodejs apps and choosing which one to expose directly to the ip address. But thanks for such elaborated solutions and multiple options!